# What is the Ramban's question in this comment on עזר כנגדו?‎

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, ramban

לא טוב היות האדם לבדו – איננו נראה שנברא האדם להיות יחיד בעולם ולא יוליד שכל הנבראים זכר ונקבה מכל בשר נבראו להקים זרע וגם העשב והעץ זרעם בהם אבל יתכן לומר כי היה כדברי האומר (ברכות סא) דו פרצופים נבראו ונעשו שיהיו בהם טבע מביא באיברי ההולדה מן הזכר לנקבה כח מוליד או תאמר זרע כפי המחלוקת הידוע בעיבור והיה הפרצוף השני עזר לראשון בתולדתו וראה הקב"ה כי טוב שיהיה העזר עומד לנגדו והוא יראנו ויפרד ממנו ויתחבר אליו כפי רצונו וזהו שאמר אעשה לו עזר כנגדו וטעם "לא טוב" שלא יאמר בו כי טוב בהיותו לבדו שלא יתקיים כן במעשה בראשית ה"טוב" הוא הקיום כאשר פירשתי במאמר "וירא אלהים כי טוב" (לעיל א ד): [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.2.18.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi)

I'm trying to understand,‎ is he saying man wouldn't have been made to live alone because all creatures can create offspring,‎ so man might have made offspring directly like a tree or grass?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is saying that every creation had the ability to reproduce, therefore Adam also did before the creation of Chavah as a separate person. The problem with man being alone was not the inability to reproduce, but that Hashem said it is better for Chavah to be physically separate from Adam.